# Setting read write permission with QFile().setPermissions()

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qfile

In my Qt 5.5.1 program I have to change my config files permission from read only to read write... I have 2 questions:

1. How can I set this permission? I have tried: `QFile(path).setPermissions(QFile::ReadWrite);` But it throws this compiler error:

   > C2664: 'bool QFile::setPermissions(const QString
   >   &,QFileDevice::Permissions)' : cannot convert argument 1 from
   >   'QIODevice::OpenModeFlag' to 'QFileDevice::Permissions' No
   >   user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this
   >   conversion, or the operator cannot be called
2. How to get the permissions of a specific file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The right way is by using the correct enum, pick a value from [`QFileDevice::Permissions`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#Permission-enum)-enum instead (I believe this is a Qt5 change). F.e.:

```
QFile(path).setPermissions(QFileDevice::ReadOwner | QFileDevice::WriteOwner);
```

To get the permissions of a file, use the [`.permissions()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#permissions) method of `QFile`:

```
QFileDevice::Permissions p = QFile(path).permissions();
```

Which returns all the file permissions OR-ed together. So to test if a certain permission is set, you can do something like:

```
if (p & QFileDevice::ReadOwner)
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you - problem solved :) One additional question: How to check if permission is NOT setted?

Comment: `if (!(p & QFileDevice::ReadOwner))` or `if ((p & QFileDevice::ReadOwner) == 0)` ?

Answer (score 4):

As stated by the compiler error you got, you were passing a `QIODevice::OpenModeFlag` enum value to `setPermissions()`, the [`QIODevice::OpenModeFlag`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#OpenModeFlag-enum) is used to describe the mode in which a device is opened.

What you need here is a combination of values from the [QFileDevice::Permission](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#Permission-enum) enum.

```
QFile(path).setPermissions(QFileDevice::ReadOwner | QFileDevice::WriteOwner);
```